# Finding Aws S3 Bucket Location

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

I have a scenario where I have to get bucket location, but the problem is that ***we don't know the bucket Region***. With getBucketLocation we need to pass bucket region, so is there any other way to get bucket region. I am using Js and Apex code for my requirement.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

here is the sample request to get the bucket location, ascendon1 is the name of the bucket, we need not pass bucket region to get the location.

we will get the data back in a callback function

[image: sample Request]

and here is output :

[image: BucketLocation]